# Real life use and explanation of the AtomicLongFieldUpdate class

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic, ocpjp

Is anybody aware of any real life use of the class [AtomicLongFieldUpdate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLongFieldUpdater.html)?
I have read the description but I have not quite grasped the meaning of it. 
Why do I want to know that? Curiosity and for OCPJP preparation.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is pretty old, so I don't know if it can be edited. But haven't you guys noticed the big typo, even in the answers? The class is called `AtomicLongFieldUpdater`, not `AtomicLongFieldUpdate`! :)

Answer (score 7):

You can think of a cost ladder for the following:

- ordinary `long`: cheap, but unsafe for multi-threaded access
- `volatile long`: more expensive, safe for multi-threaded access, atomic operations not possible
- `AtomicLong`: most expensive, safe for multi-threaded access, atomic operations possible

(When I say 'unsafe' or 'not possible' I mean 'without an external mechanism like synchronization' of course.)

In the case where multi-threaded access is needed, but most operations are simple reads or writes, with only a few atomic operations needed, you can create one static instance of `AtomicLongFieldUpdate` and use this when atomic updates are needed. The memory/runtime overhead is then similar to a simple `volatile` variable, except for the atomic operations which are of the order of (or slightly more expensive than) the ordinary `AtomicLong` operations.

Here is a [nice little tutorial](http://javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_7_atomic_updaters.shtml).

Comment: Just to add some more info.  `AtomicLong` is only more "expensive" than `volatile long` in that there is a wrapper class -- so slightly more memory overhead.  Also, `volatile long` is not "safe for multi-threaded access` if you are doing `++`.

Comment: Also the memory overhead of `AtomicLongFieldUpdate` us going to be much more than just a simple `AtomicLong`.  And the runtime is going to be slower than both `volatile long` and `AtomicLong` since it is using reflection.

Comment: @Gray You can use 1 static instance of ALFU, so the memory overhead is not as huge as you might think. Also, I think (not sure) that reflection is only used to set up the field, not on every access; plus in recent HotSpot versions the operation is [intrinsified](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7023898). The exact cost model (memory and runtime) is going to depend on JRE and JVM implementation.

Comment: You are correct about the 1 static instance.  Reflection _has_ to be used on every access otherwise the 1 static won't work @rxg.

Comment: @Gray I had a peek at the implementation in the Oracle JDK. There are two different implementations depending on the capability of the underlying JVM (one uses synchronize the other doesn't lock), but both do the most expensive reflection work in their constructors, delegating to `sun.misc.Unsafe` for the real `compareAndSet` - so the set up is more expensive, but I would expect the runtime cost to just a bit higher than ordinary `AtomicLong`.

Answer (score 6):

The reason why you would use e.g. AtomicLongFieldUpdater in favor to AtomicLong is simply to reduce the heap cost. Internally both work pretty much the same on th compareAndSet level which both use sun.misc.Unsafe at the end.

Consider you have a certain class that is initialized 1000k times. With AtomicLong you'd create 1000k AtomicLongs. With AtomicLongFieldUpdater on the other hand, you'd create 1 CONSTANT AtomicLongFieldUpdater and 1000k long primitives which of course does not need so much heap space.

Answer (score 2):

> Is anybody aware of any real life use of the `AtomicLongFieldUpdate` class?

I've never used this class myself but in doing a get usage on my workspace I see a couple "real life" instances of its use:

- [`com.google.common.util.concurrent.AtomicDouble`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AtomicDouble.html) uses it to atomically modify their internal `volatile long` field which stores the bits from a `double` using `Number.doubleToRawLongBits(...)`.  Pretty cool.
- `net.sf.ehcache.Element` uses it to atomically update the `hitCount` field.

> I have read the description but I have not quite grasped the meaning of it.

It basically provides the same functionality as `AtomicLong` but on a field local to another class.  The memory load of the `AtomicLongFieldUpdate` is less than the `AtomicLong` in that  you configure one instance of the update for each field so lower memory overhead but more CPU overhead (albeit maybe small) from the reflection.

The javadocs say:

> This class is designed for use in atomic data structures in which several fields of the same node are independently subject to atomic updates.

Sure but then I'd just use multiple `Atomic*` fields.  Just about the only reason why I'd use the class is if there was an existing class that I could not change that I wanted to increment atomically.

Answer (score 1):

Of course. I have been reading [Alibaba Druid](https://github.com/alibaba/druid) recently. I found `AtomicLongFieldUpdater`  is used in this project widely.

```
// stats
    private volatile long                    recycleErrorCount         = 0L;
    private volatile long                    connectErrorCount         = 0L;
protected static final AtomicLongFieldUpdater<DruidDataSource> recycleErrorCountUpdater
            = AtomicLongFieldUpdater.newUpdater(DruidDataSource.class, "recycleErrorCount");
    protected static final AtomicLongFieldUpdater<DruidDataSource> connectErrorCountUpdater
            = AtomicLongFieldUpdater.newUpdater(DruidDataSource.class, "connectErrorCount");
```

As defined above, the properties `recycleErrorCount` and `connectErrorCount` are used to count error occurrence times.
Quite a lot of `DataSource` (The class that holds properties above) will be created during an application lifetime in which case using `ALFU` reduces heap space consumption obviously than using `AtomicLong`.

Answer (score -3):

Atomics are usually used in parallel programming.

Under the work-stealing mode, it only supports async, finish, forasync, isolated, and atomic variables.

You can view atomic as a safe protection from data race and other problems that you need to concern in parallel programming.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question which is specifically about `AtomicLongFieldUpdate`.