# Why do AtomicLong and AtomicLongFieldUpdater implement compareAndSet differently?

Tags: java, compare-and-swap

From the source code of `AtomicLong`:

```
    public final boolean compareAndSet(long expect, long update) {
        return unsafe.compareAndSwapLong(this, valueOffset, expect, update);
    }
```

From the source code of `AtomicLongFieldUpdater`:

```
    public static <U> AtomicLongFieldUpdater<U> newUpdater(Class<U> tclass,
                                                           String fieldName) {
        Class<?> caller = Reflection.getCallerClass();
        if (AtomicLong.VM_SUPPORTS_LONG_CAS)
            return new CASUpdater<U>(tclass, fieldName, caller);
        else
            return new LockedUpdater<U>(tclass, fieldName, caller);
    }

    // CASUpdater extends AtomicLongFieldUpdater
        public final boolean compareAndSet(T obj, long expect, long update) {
            accessCheck(obj);
            return U.compareAndSwapLong(obj, offset, expect, update);
        }

    // LockedUpdater extends AtomicLongFieldUpdater
        public final boolean compareAndSet(T obj, long expect, long update) {
            accessCheck(obj);
            synchronized (this) {
                long v = U.getLong(obj, offset);
                if (v != expect)
                    return false;
                U.putLong(obj, offset, update);
                return true;
            }
        }
```

My question is why the two classes use different ways to update a long value? I. e. why does `AtomicLongFieldUpdater` conditionally fallback to the locking approach, while `AtomicLong` doesn't?

Comment: Relates to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46817970/compareandset-on-processors-that-does-not-support-cas-operation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17239568/real-life-use-and-explanation-of-the-atomiclongfieldupdate-class. But none of the pages seem to question "why the difference"...

Answer (score 0):

Both classes basically serve the same purpose, they both use the internal `Unsafe` class which does the "hard low-level" work. So it's only logical to question the implementation discrepancy.

I *guess* that the fallback done in `AtomicLongFieldUpdater` is maybe just a relic. This *could* be supported by the fact that `VM_SUPPORTS_LONG_CAS` is defined in the `AtomicLong`, but used only in the `AtomicLongFieldUpdater`.

Another possibility is that Java authors decided to somewhat optimize performance, but they did it just in the `AtomicLongFieldUpdater`.

The answer may be hidden in the javadoc of the `VM_SUPPORTS_LONG_CAS`:

```
    /**
     * Records whether the underlying JVM supports lockless
     * compareAndSwap for longs. While the Unsafe.compareAndSwapLong
     * method works in either case, some constructions should be
     * handled at Java level to avoid locking user-visible locks.
     */
    static final boolean VM_SUPPORTS_LONG_CAS = VMSupportsCS8();
```

I'm afraid we would have to ask authors directly to know the exact reasoning and meaning. It seems like nearly the same code was there already back in Java 5 - see the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/tree/319a3b994703aac84df7bcde272adfcb3cdbbbf0/jdk/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/atomic) from the OpenJDK's "initial load" commit from 2007. I think it's hard to get to commits before this one...

Comment: Fun fact: these parts are present in the "src.zip" accompanying the older, closed source JDKs too. A blessed soul has 1.5.0 on GitHub: https://github.com/fanhongtao/JDK/tree/jdk_1.5.0/src/java/util/concurrent/atomic (but it does not contain anything else what OP and you have seen already).